# Passing parameters of different type to function defined on interface in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I want to apply a set of rules to a collection of business objects. These are simple rules and I wouldn't want to use any existing business rules engine.

I need to pass different context to each of the rules, so every rule, in theory, might need different parameters. Below is how I'm currently doing it. Is there any other/better way?

Note: I've evaluated using the Visitor pattern, but seems like too much effort for this particular scenario. The actual rules are not much more complicated that what I have on the example.

```
interface IParamBase {}

interface IParam : IParamBase
{
    string MyProperty {get; set;}
}

class Param : IParam
{
    public string MyProperty {get; set;}
}

interface IRule
{
    void Setup(IParamBase param);
    void Apply(BusinessObject businessObject);
}

class Rule :IRule
{
    IParam _param;
    public void Apply(BusinessObject businessObject)
    {
        businessObject.AssignedFromRule = _param.MyProperty;
        Console.WriteLine(businessObject.AssignedFromRule);
    }

    public void Setup(IParamBase param)
    {
        _param = param as IParam;
    }
}

class BusinessObject
{
    public string AssignedFromRule {get; set;}
}

void Main()
{
    var rule = new Rule();
    var param = new Param();
    param.MyProperty = "my property";
    BusinessObject businessObject = new BusinessObject();
    rule.Setup(param);
    rule.Apply(businessObject);
}
```

Update: I forgot to add to the sample my need of downcasting.

Comment: Nice question but I think it applies better to Code Review.

Comment: If you are trying to setup a business object with a collection of rules, I think you are looking for a factory. Your example doesn't show when the rule is evaluated. Various evaluation strategies may merit the visitor pattern, but your example isn't that developed.

Comment: @Adriano: Agree, is just for the convenience, and out of custom. I also guess SO has more traffic than any other StackExchange site, so maybe I've got better chances to talk to you guys here :)

Comment: @JoshC.: I'd say a factory is a pattern to deal with object creation, which is a different problem. My example only contains one rule and one object, if you put all the rules in a collection<IRule> and put all objects in a collection of objects, you could iterate over them and apply them. The rule is evaluated in the "Apply" method.

Comment: @julio.g I see. From your Apply method, I only see an assignment, which looks like injection, not evaluation. Since I thought you were setting up an object, I recommended the factory.

Comment: If I understand the question : seems somehow related to Open/Closed Principal too..

Comment: Are your rules validation rules, or something that updates the business objects (like, for example, an ApplySalesTaxRule / ApplyShippingCostsRule)?

Comment: @tcarvin: Not validating, but updating, depending on certain context that needs to be passed at every evaluation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is effectively the Visitor pattern. It would be clearer if the business object had a method like BusinessObject.Apply(BusinessRule rule) { rule.apply(this); };

It serves the same purpose as the full-blown implementation: You can add operations (business rules) without extending the object that the operations are performed on (the business object).

You might be interested in using Composite so you can apply a set of rules as one rule. You also might be interested in being a little more explicit about the calsses you use in your Visitor implementation, but if it works for you, go for it.

Comment: You're right Anders, the scenario is best fitted for the Visitor pattern.

Comment: The cool thing is that it's a great example for why Visitor makes sense. If you want to read and compile rules from a configuration file then use them at runtime there's no substitute. Imagine you wrote a simple language for business rules, then wrote your rules in a file that was read at startup, essentially an interpreter...